# Javascript pass var

Tags: javascript

I'm having a little problem. I'm new in JS and I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to get a list of friends from Facebook. To do that I'm using the user posts and I want to show only the duplicates. My first answer is how to show all the friends from a loop and get only the duplicates (I want only one or two objects) and second is how to pass a var from a function to another function because I want to POST all the infos to a php file.

This is what I did:

```
function getInfo() {
    FB.api(
        '/me',
        'GET',
        {fields: 'first_name'}, 
        function(response) {
            friends();
            var myname = response.first_name;
            $.post(
                "file.php",
                { myname:myname,friendsname:friendsname },
                function(data) { $("body").append(data); }
            );  
        }
```

With this function I'm getting my first name.

```
function friends() {
    FB.api(
       '/me/posts?fields=likes{id,name}',
        {limit:50},
        function(response) {
            if (response.data) {
                $.each(response.data,function(index, posts) {
                    var posturi = posts.likes;
                        $.each(posturi.data, function(useri, lista) {
                            var friendsname = lista.name;
                        });
                }); 
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And this is the list with my friends. If I check `console.log(friendsname)` it gives me all the friends with duplicates. But if I write an `innerHTML` in that `$.each` it returns me only 1 object. And how can I pass `friendsname` from `friends()` to `getInfo()` so I can post to that .php file?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're overwriting the value of `innerHTML` in every loop of `$.each`.

Try this:

```
var posturi = posts.likes;
var names = posturi.data.map(function(item) { return item.name; }).join(', ');
```

`names` will contain a comma separated list of names.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine! Only this please, how can i make the var names to be global because i want to use it in the function getInfo() so i can post it to the file.php. And how can i select if i want only one user, or three or how much i want if i have more users. Something like names[1];. Thank you!

Comment: Why store globals? Just pass them as an [argument](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) to the `getInfo()` function.

For filtering stuff out, you can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I suggest you read more about javascript and open new questions in case you're lost somewhere else.